# Row span based on array length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a dynamic table(td) and trying to export it to excel in that I have some repeating rows the repeating rows depend on the array length how can I add row span for that

```
var comments = `<td>${sequenceVariantDetails[i].comments}</td>`
```

Comment: Is `comments` an array and is it its length you want to use?

Comment: no it is td i have created

Comment: i need to use row span it depends on array length not fixed value

Comment: But which array? There is literally no information on your question.

Comment: innersection[k] is my array row span is not fixed depends on k

Comment: And where is that in your code?

Comment: can we assign array length to  row span attribute inside td

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248925/discussion-between-shreeja-kotian-and-terry).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
var comments =''
sequenceVariantDetails.forEach(index => comments += `<td>${sequenceVariantDetails[index].comments}</td>`)
```

Comment: i need to use innersection[k] as array

Comment: i want to use row span based on array length innersection[k]